# Showing content behind Navigation Bar

Tags: android

I'm currently working on something where I want the status and navigation bars to be transparent, with the content going behind them. Currently, I have the bars set to @android:color/transparent in styles.xml and am able to get the content behind the status bar with this code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            );
```

However I am still struggling to get it behind the nav bar. Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 15):

You need:

```
getWindow()
  .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Check out the answer here:

[Showing content behind status and navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527229/showing-content-behind-status-and-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 10):

Try to add these in your activity's `style.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

hope this can help.